# Is PID with one divisible element a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a PID and $r\in R$ be the divisible element i.e. for any $a\in R$ there exists $y\in R$ s.t. $r=ay$. Can we imply that $R$ is a field?

Comment: If $r$ is cancellable then $\,x\neq0\,$ and $\,rx\mid r\Rightarrow x\mid 1\Rightarrow x\,$ is a unit. In a domain $r$ is cancellable $\!\iff\! r\neq 0.\ $ Note that you need to assume $\,r\neq 0,\,$ and $\,a\neq 0\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint: Let $x\in R$, and $a=rx$.  Then we can find $y$ such that $r=ay=rxy$.  What does this tell us?

Comment: OP forgot the condition $r\neq0$, which your hint implicitly assumes (otherwise $r=0$ works in any PID). Then, the condition is actually never satisfied, unless we weaken it to only hold for $a\neq0$. Your hint makes sense then, as soon as one takes $x\neq0$ (and otherwise we'd be claiming $0$ invertible, which cannot happen).

Comment: That makes sense and all elements of $R$ are invertible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any non-zero $a\in R$, by definition $r\in(a)$. But $r$ is divisible by $r^2$ too, i.e. $r=xr^2$ for an $x\in R$; hence (assuming $r\neq 0$) $1=xr$, as $R$ is a domain.

If the ideal $(a)$ contains a unit, $a$ is a unit.